# jQuery - How to make a sliding website like the apps of Windows Phone

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7

In some of the apps of Windows Phone 7 or above when we slide our finger through the screen it takes us to the different section of that app by moving the background and the content at the same time but the background moving fast and the content faster. I want the same functionality in my website, instead of sliding a finger through the screen I have links on which when we will click it will slide us to the different section of the page, with the background background moving fast and the text faster.

Can anybody tell me how to do that with jQuery, HTML and CSS?

**"Any Help World be appreciated"**

Comment: The name of the effect you are looking for is "parallax".  Can't help you on an HTML implementation of it, but that may assist your searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin has helped me in the past: http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/